# Plane Curve invariants via Contour Integrals

Tags: cv.complex-variables, at.algebraic-topology

We learn in complex analysis class how to find the winding number of the contour $\Gamma$ around the origin.
\[    n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{dz}{z}    = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint d(\log z)
=  \frac{1}{2\pi } \oint d\theta \]
My goal had been to count the number of [self-intersections of curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90856/computing-self-intersections-with-complex-analysis).  I guessed some integral over a torus $\Gamma \times \Gamma$ which would have a pole-like object whenever $z_1 = z_2$.  In the back of my mind, I worried  maybe integrating along $t_1 = t_2$ would have zero contribution.
\[  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \oint \frac{dz_1 dz_2}{z_1 - z_2}  \]

Inspired by [Kontsevich's integral for knots](http://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/VassilievKnot.pdf) (and some more recent papers), I learned of something that comes close
\[   \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \oint \frac{dz_1  - dz_2}{z_1 - z_2} 
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \oint d \log(z_1 - z_2) 
=  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \oint \arg (z_1 - z_2)  \]
So formulas like these are measuring how the chords of curves wind around each other.  This seems to be known as the Whitney invariant for plane curves, counting *signed* self-intersections.

[image]

Is there a way to get self-intersections all of the same sign?  This must be related the Vassiliev invariants as well, but I'd like to focus on plane curves.

Comment: This measure blows up when the curve is self-tangent, since if you go one way it has 2 intersection and if you go the other way it has 0. Therefore, you need to integrate something that has a pole or is otherwise not well-defined when the curve is self-tangent. This seems hard, because for it to be self-tangent $(z_1-z_2)$ and $d(z_1-z_2)$ both have to be zero.