# Estimate self crossings of a curve parameterized by a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fourier-analysis, trigonometric-polynomials

Given z on the unit circle, let $P(z)= \sum\limits_{k=-D}^D p_k z^k $.
Can one estimate the number of self crossings of the following curve with an analytic expression in terms of the coefficients $\{p_k\}$?
$$
        P(e^{i * \theta}), \theta \in [0, 2pi)
$$

Comment: Related (but also unanswered) http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90856

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma(x) = (\alpha(x), \beta(x)),$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are the real and imaginary parts. A self-intersection corresponds to a simultaneous zero of $(\alpha(x)-\alpha(y))/(x-y)$ and $(\beta(x)-\beta(y)/(x-y),$ If you use the rational parametrization for the circle (the $\tan t/2$ trick), both expressions become polynomials, and the number of self-intersections is basically the number of real roots of the resultant. So, when the smoke clears, you are asking for an analytic formula for the number of real roots of a polynomial. This can be expressed as a mapping degree (see, for example, Edelman and Kostlan's BAMS article on zeros of random polynomial), which is close, but not exactly, what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the rational paramterization idea, as this never occurred to me.  In your response, you say "the number of self-intersections is basically the number of real roots of the resultant".  I can interpret this in one of two ways.  On e way is to fix x and consider the resulting polynomial a polynomial in y.  The number of real roots in y will be the number of curve crossings through x's image-point (not exactly what I was asking).  Another interpretation is to consider the resulting expression a bi-variate polynomial in (x,y) and analyze its real roots.  Which did you mean?

Comment: @Jim I mean neither. but rather http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant